# Issue on installing LibreOffice on Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dependencies, libreoffice

Recently I upgraded my Ubuntu installation from 18.04 to 20.04.1, but after upgrading LibreOffice is not available by default. When I try to install it by running:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice libreoffice-gtk
```

I'm getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice :
**Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed**
    **Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-python but it is not
going to be installed** 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
broken packages.
```

I tried to fix the broken packages and tried various solutions I found on Stack Overflow, but nothing works for me.

**What I've tried so far:**

*way1:*

```
$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

*way2:*

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

way3:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list


# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable # disabled on upgrade to focal
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

What can I do now?

Comment: First run `sudo apt install -f` and then try again to install libreoffice.

Comment: When was the last time you did system updates?  You need to update your package list `sudo apt update` and update packages `sudo apt upgrade` before making any changes to your software

Comment: I did both but it doesn't fix my issue sir

Comment: "*Held broken packages*" means that you created a version conflict, usually by installing wrong-version or wrong-release packages from non-Ubuntu sources.. If you previously installed a newer version of Libreoffice onto your older 18.04 from some PPA or other non-Ubuntu source, then uninstall that older version completely.

Comment: Post the entire unredacted outputs of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` into the body of your question using monospace font and retaining all line breaks

Comment: Something is wrong with your repositories. Please post output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @Pilot6 sir. added `sources.list` info. Please have a look